# How to download hundreds of confidential files from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using S3 to store a bunch of confidential files for clients. The bucket can not have public access and only authenticated users can access these files.

**This is my current idea**

I'm using Cognito to authenticate the user and allow them to access API Gateway. When they make a request to the path `/files`, it directs the request to a lambda, which generates a signed url for every file that the user has access too. Then API Gateway returns the list of all these signed urls and the browser displays them.

Gathering a signed url for every file seems very inefficient. Is there any other way to get confidential files from S3 in one large batch?

Answer (score 2):

A safer approach would be for your application to generate signed URLs, valid for a single request or period, and have your bucket accept only requests originating from CloudFront using an Origin Access Identity.

See the documentation for this at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Comment: As you stated `A safer approach would be for your application to generate signed URLs`, how is this different than from what I suggest in my question, about the Lambda generating the signed urls? I understand the part about CloudFront, but can you elaborate more about your signed url part.

Comment: @GaryHoliday I meant you can generate signed url's on any compute, it's not an API call, not necessary to invoke a lambda function just for that... If you can't  change the URLs, you could use Signed Cookies instead.

Answer (score 1):

You say "Gathering a signed url for every file seems very inefficient", but the process of creating the Signed URL itself is very easy — just a few lines of code.

However, if there are many files, it would put a lot of work on your users to download each file individually.

Therefore, another approach could be:

- Identify all the files they wish to download
- **Create a Zip** of the files and store it in Amazon S3
- Provide a **Signed URL** to the Zip file
- **Delete** the Zip file later (since it is not required anymore), possibly by creating a lifecycle rule on a folder within the bucket

Please note that AWS Lambda functions have a disk storage limit of 500MB, which might not be enough to create the Zip file.